# Android Studio 3.1.2 - Lombok throws error and asks for non existing option

Tags: java, plugins, android-studio-3.0, lombok

Every time I open my project, Lombok throws this error:

[image]

Problem: mentioned option does not exist in Android Studio settings:

[image]

I have latest lombok plugin installed:

[image]

I have added lombok dependencies to my build.gradle:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.22'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.22'
```

Comment: I just checked, and the option it refers to is in *IntelliJ*, I'm not sure if Android Studio has an equivalent (though since Android Studio normally defers the build to Gradle I am puzzled why it would be necessary)

Comment: Hmh it seems to be Lombok issue then, they just did not make it properly for Android and Android studio. Maybe it refers to some newer InteliJ build, Android Studio uses pretty old InteliJ version as its base

Comment: @user1209216 did you check my answer?

Comment: Sorry, not yet it suddenly stopped throwing that error without any action from my side. Weird

Comment: I'm getting the same error message again. Any solution welcomed

Comment: @user1209216 You can try my solution :)

Comment: Not working, also option you proposed causes Lombok's constructor annotation stop working. I guess I will finally perform delombok to get rid that crap

Answer (score 0):

### **Enable annotation processing:**

---

**1.** Close the project: File -> close project
**2.** In "Welcome to Android Studio" window:
Configure -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Enable annotation processing

### Then, you have to install lombok plugin and add it to your module:

---

**3.** Install **Lombok** plugin in android studio :
File -> Setting -> Plugins -> Search for Lombok -> install -> Restart IDE

**4.** **Build.gradle** file of your **module** :

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'     
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
}
```

**5.** Create a **lombok.config** file in **root folder of your project** and add the below to it (`@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` will work) :

```
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true
```

**6. Sync** the module.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this **"lombok.config"** in your project,It's working for me

**lombok.config**

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addGeneratedAnnotation = false
lombok.accessors.chain = false
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true
```

Comment: Not working for me. I've tried adding this config file but I get the same issue everytime.